# How can I use Snowflakes "least" with Pypika?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, pypika

Snowflake has a function called [LEAST](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html) which can be applied to two columns and returns the lower value for each row.

How can I use that function when building a SnowflakeQuery with pypika?

Answer (score 3):

Pypika allows you to [define additional functions](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/4_extending.html#sql-functions-not-included-in-pypika) not provided in their default function lists.

To define [`LEAST`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/least.html) in it, the following form can be used, mirroring [`pypika.functions.Concat`](https://pypika.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pypika/functions.html#Concat) that also uses a similar variable-argument signature:

```py
class Least(Function):
    def __init__(self, *terms, **kwargs):
        super(Least, self).__init__('LEAST', *terms, **kwargs)
```

Example usage:

```py
>>> from pypika.functions import Function

>>> class Least(Function):
...     def __init__(self, *terms, **kwargs):
...         super(Least, self).__init__('LEAST', *terms, **kwargs)
... 

>>> q = Query.from_(customers).select(
...     customers.id,
...     Least(3, 2, 1).as_('least_example'),
... )

>>> q
SELECT "id",LEAST(3,2,1) "least_example" FROM "customers"
```